# Reading DB credentials in Laravel from files outside laravel core

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry if the question is trivial for someone but I wasn't be able to make it and to find answer so far. In `Laravel` we have DB credentials in `app/config/database.php`

```
'connections' => array(
    ...

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'myDB',
        'username'  => 'myUser',
        'password'  => 'myPass',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    ...
),
```

Now I have 2 custom files one in `public` directory and one in `libraries` directory which also got db credentials in them

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPass";
$dbname = "myDB"; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Is there a way somehow to include `app/config/database.php` in those files and read DB credentials from instead of have DB credentials in 3 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If test.php would live inside your public folder:

```
// test.php
$config = include __DIR__ . '/../app/config/database.php';
// var_dump($config);

$servername = $config['connections']['mysql']['host'];
$username   = $config['connections']['mysql']['username'];
$password   = $config['connections']['mysql']['password'];
$dbname     = $config['connections']['mysql']['database']; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the `app/config/database.php` file and then read the credentials from there.

Inside your custom files it would just be a matter of using `include 'path_to/app/config/database.php';` and then you can access the connections array from there. To help us generate a file path we can use the `__DIR__` [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php);

```
include __DIR__ . '/../app/config/database.php';
$conn = new mysqli(connections['mysql']['host'], connections['mysql']['username'], connections['mysql']['password'], connections['mysql']['database']);
```